# Nesting PHP (to implement master & content pages)

Tags: php, master-pages

Here I thought I was being smart.  Using PHP, I created a master page, `master.php`, that injects one of a selection of content pages: `content1.php`, `content2.php`, etc.  It didn't occur to me that I'd like to be able to use PHP in the content pages.

The master injects content like this:

```
<?php
if($pageContentHtml != '') {
    echo $pageContentHtml;
}
?>
```

Of course, when `$pageContentHtml` contains any `<?php ?>` blocks, the page does not render as desired.

I read about using PHP's `ob_*` functions to buffer the output but I couldn't quite figure out whether this will let me do what I want.  Will it?  Is this possible?

Sample `content.php` file:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque...</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <?php
            $bookFileNames = array(
                "book-cover1.jpg"
                ,"book-cover2.jpg"
                ,"book-cover3.jpg"
                ,"book-cover4.jpg"
                .
                .
                .
            );

            for($i=0; $i<count($bookFileNames); ++i) {
                echo '<a href="/images/books/' . $bookFileNames[$i] . '" class="book-title" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="book-covers"><img src="/images/books/' . $bookFileNames[$i] . '" class="img-fluid"></a>';
            }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without knowing what $pageContentHtml contains or what's in the other PHP files, we won't be of much help. ob_start() might help but it's hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think it mattered.  At least, I was hoping since this is a general master page solution that it wouldn't matter.  The content contains HTML that might contain PHP.  I'll add an example.  I *was* hoping to include "inline"? PHP rather than loading it from a file.

Comment: I added the content sample.  Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `include()` or `require()` to include the content pages, rather than read in their contents. When included, PHP will be processed as normal:

```
include('content1.php');
```

Comment: I didn't realize the OP was NOT doing that. I just thought it was incomplete code. Craig, this is how you properly include other PHP code in to your existing file in order to be processed....

Comment: If I understand correctly, the content should a PHP file and if the content contains HTML, which it mostly is, then it should use echo()?

Comment: @CraigSilver that file can contain HTML and also PHP (the PHP would need to be properly surrounded by `<?php` and `?>` tags), `echo()` not necessary unless you want HTML somewhere embedded inside other PHP code.

Comment: Ah yes, I just tested that.  I had made the incorrect assumption that an included PHP file would contain PHP code, similar to how an included JavaScript file contains JavaScript.  I was doing something unnecessarily fancy instead of using `include('content1.php');`.  I'll accept this answer.  Thank you.